# By whom, how and where was the video in The Ring made?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-ring

I've read that there are multiple versions (e.g. Japanese) and sequels of The Ring, I'm talking about the [US version from 2002](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298130/). I've not watched other versions.

Many answers regarding this movie are found on the net, but I got stuck with this one. Who made the **video** and how was the video made? Where was it made?

Read on multiple sites Samara made the tape by herself. How? I know why it was made and why those images were used. But can she give her imagination a physical form? Or was the video made in the hospital? Was it the project that Noah found later in hospital files? Or is there any other story behind the video creation?

And an extra question, how did that video get into the cabin 12 at the beginning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the beginning of the film Katie explains to Becca how she saw the tape. Katie and some of her friends stayed at the motel/cabin. While there, they tried recording a football game on the VCR in the room that, as it turned out. sat directly over the well where Samara died. Somehow (this part is unexplained by design) the strange images were imposed onto the tape at this time, probably due to proximity to the body. When the kids tried to watch the game, they saw what was on the tape.

Quote from Katie:

> "We played the tape. The game wasn't there. It was something else. We thought it was some kind of sick joke. And then the phone rang."

After they left, the motel manager cleaned the room and put the tape on his video shelf (he tells the reporter that people leave tapes behind all the time, and that is how he built his collection).

This won't answer all your questions as to how, but the supernatural elements are not meant to be explained.

Comment: Wow, this does indeed sound like a reasonable explanation. But when was this explained in the movie? I can't remember this at all. Or was it from a sequel/prequel/original/whatever?

Comment: The first bit of exposition happens in the first five minutes of the film. See my edits.

Comment: This explains enough. She had evil powers so she surely can alter the video tape at the time of recording as it was just on top of that well. Also we saw later that see had effect on normal photo camera too. Makes sense. Great. Thanks